WordPress disable Notice and Deprecated in debug.log
I want to get rid of Notice and Deprecated errors in my debug.log
here is my wp-config.php
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false ); 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
mu-plugins/error-reporting.php
// Disable notices, warnings, deprecated, and strict errors globally
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);
// Ensure that display_errors is turned off
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1); // Enable logging of errors to error log
in php.ini
I have Master value error_reporting = 6133
but local value is 8181
How can I override it and make sure plugins won't override it again?
I tried to change it inside php.ini / wp-config.php / mu-plugin, but it's still doesn't work and I'm getting Notices in my debug.log

Check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_debug_mode/
